# Comparable implementation for Generic Type?

Tags: java, oop, generics, comparable

I am currently implementing a custom Supplier that requires implementation of a Comparable.

Since my class implements Comparable, it is a must that I implement the compareTo() myself. However, being a Generic Type , how do I compare the values? As they could be almost anything.

```
class CachedSupplier<T> implements Comparable<T>{
    private Supplier<? extends T> supplier;
    private T value;
    boolean isAvailable;

    public CachedSupplier(Supplier<? extends T> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public T get() {
        if (!isAvailable) {
            value = supplier.get();
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public int compareTo(T o) {
        return get().compareTo(o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can require that `T` implements `Comparable<T>`:

```
class CachedSupplier<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

Now, if you still need the `CachedSupplier` itself to implement `Comparable<T>` (which I'm not sure you do), you can use `T`'s `compareTo()` method:

```
class CachedSupplier<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<T>
{
    private Supplier<? extends T> supplier;
    private T value;
    boolean isAvailable;

    public CachedSupplier(Supplier<? extends T> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public T get() {
        if (!isAvailable) {
            value = supplier.get();
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public int compareTo(T o) {
        return get().compareTo(o);
    }
}
```

EDIT: As Andreas commented, if your `CachedSupplier` has to implement `Comparable`, it should probably implement `Comparable<CachedSupplier<T>>` not `Comparable<T>`:

```
class CachedSupplier<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<CachedSupplier<T>>
{
    private Supplier<? extends T> supplier;
    private T value;
    boolean isAvailable;

    public CachedSupplier(Supplier<? extends T> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public T get() {
        if (!isAvailable) {
            value = supplier.get();
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public int compareTo(CachedSupplier<T> o) {
        return get().compareTo(o.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: A type should be `Comparable` with itself (SELF), which is why you have `T extends Comparable<T>`, i.e. the `Comparable` type parameter is the type extending `Comparable`. This also means that `CachedSupplier` has to implement `Comparable<SELF>`, but SELF is `CachedSupplier<T>`, not `T`. Which then makes the method `compareTo(CachedSupplier<T> o)`, allowing you to implement the method correctly, so it actually compares `this.value` with `o.value` (indirectly though `get()` for the lazy loading).

Comment: And in my main class which uses my CachedSupplier, how should I declare it?

It is currently: private CachedSupplier<T> supplier; (but does not work). What should the type be now? I've tried private CachedSupplier<T extends Comparable<T>> supplier; which did not work

Comment: @Iva You should decide which type to instantiate it with. For example `CachedSupplier<Double> doubleSupplier = new CachedSupplier<>(Math::random);` or `CachedSupplier<Long> longSupplier = new CachedSupplier<>(System::currentTimeMillis);`

Comment: @Eran But it needs to be a generic type, because I am implementing the CachedSupplier in my SpecialStream (which is also custom coded), and one of the variable is the CachedSupplier I created.

Comment: @Iva In order to instantiate a `CachedSupplier`, you must pass to it some `Supplier` instance, so you must choose which type of objects your `Supplier` produces.